# NodeJs & Express

Tags: express

I am trying to run `ExpressJs` for my app but I encounter the same error every time. Can any one help me regarding this?

```
nodejs app.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'serve-favicon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ankit/Desktop/Sample1July/nodetest1/app.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: What happen if you try do install the missing package?

Comment: do `npm install serve-favicon --save` and then `nodejs app.js`

Comment: You should provide some more details about the steps what you followed to create and run the node project.

Comment: I am using Linux OS and I am sure that their is no Installation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in console

```
npm install
```

After that:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

You required module 'serve-favicon', but not installed it.

"Error: Cannot find module 'serve-favicon'"You need install with npm:

```
npm i
```